# Error "The given key was not present in the dictionary" When Creating New Custom Entity on Update Event

Tags: plugins, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

On CRM 2013 on-premise, I'm trying to write a plugin that triggers when an update is made to a field on Quote. The plugin then creates a new custom entity "new_contract".

My plugin is successfully triggered when the update to that field is made. However I keep getting an error message "The given key was not present in the dictionary" when trying to create the new custom entity.

I'm using a "PostImage" in this code. I confirm that it's registered using the same name in Plugin Registration.

Here is the code

```
var targetEntity = context.GetParameterCollection<Entity>
                   (context.InputParameters, "Target");
if (targetEntity == null)
  {throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(OperationStatus.Failed, 
            "Target Entity cannot be null")}
var postImage = context.PostEntityImages["PostImage"];
if (postImage == null)
  {throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(OperationStatus.Failed, 
            "Post Image is required");}

var quote = context.GenerateCompositeEntity(targetEntity, postImage);
//throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(OperationStatus.Failed, "Update is captured");
//Guid QuoteId = (Guid)quote.Attributes["quoteid"];
var serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider
                       .GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
var service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

var contractEntity = new Entity();
contractEntity = new Entity("new_contract");
if (quote.Attributes.Contains("portfolio"))
{
  var quotePortfolio = (EntityReference)quote.Attributes["new_portfolio];
  contractEntity[Schema.new_contract.PortfolioName] = 
       new EntityReference(quotePortfolio.LogicalName, quotePortfolio.Id);
}
if (quote.Attributes.Contains(Schema.Quote.QuoteName))
{
  var quoteName = (string)quote.Attributes["name"];
  contractEntity[Schema.new_contract.contractName] = quoteName;
}
var contractId = service.Create(contractEntity);
```

Comment: Show your full method. You are using `var` for your declaration, so the types of each are unclear in what you have posted.

Answer (score 1):

I think context does not contain "PostImage" attribute.You should check context to see whether it contains the attribute before getting the data.

Comment: But I've already added to throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException when postImage == null. It should've thrown this error but in my case it does not.

Comment: If context contains only one record you can try context[0].Attributes.Contains("PostImage"). If context has PostImage attributes you can fill the "postImage" object.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this line in your post above:

```
var service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
```

I am deducing that the type of your `context` variable is `LocalPluginContext` (since this contains the `UserId` value) which does not expose the images (as another answer states).

To access the images, you need to get to the *Plugin Execution Context*:

```
IPluginExecutionContext pluginContext = context.PluginExecutionContext;

Entity postImage = null;
if (pluginContext.PostEntityImages != null && pluginContext.PostEntityImages.Contains("PostImage))
{
    postImage = pluginContext.PostEntityImages["PostImage"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion unfortunately this part doesn't work IPluginExecutionContext pluginContext = context.PluginExecutionContext;

Answer (score 0):

In the below code segment, you are checking for the attribute "portfolio" and using "new_portfolio". Can you correct that and let us know whether that worked.

```
if (quote.Attributes.Contains("portfolio"))
        {
            var quotePortfolio = (EntityReference)quote.Attributes["new_portfolio];
            contractEntity[Schema.new_contract.PortfolioName] = new EntityReference(quotePortfolio.LogicalName, quotePortfolio.Id);
        }
```

Comment: A bad copy-paste on my end; both should have been "new_portfolio". Thanks for noticing it though.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't say what line is throwing the exception. Put in the VS debugger and find the line that is throwing the exception.

I did see that you are trying to read from a dictionary here without first checking if the dictionary contains the key, that can be the source of this exception.

```
var postImage = context.PostEntityImages["PostImage"];

if (postImage == null) 
    throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(OperationStatus.Failed, 
    "Post Image is required");
```

Try this:

```
if(!context.PostEntityImages.Contains("PostImage") ||
   context.PostEntityImages["PostImage"] == null)
   InvalidPluginExecutionException(OperationStatus.Failed, "Post Image is required");

var postImage = context.PostEntityImages["PostImage"];
```

Although, I don't think that a PostEntityImage Value will ever be null, if it passes the `Contains` test you don't really need the null check.